# How to convert List<Map<String,Object>> to Map<String, String>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a value like below,

```
[{S.No=1, Column2=Data2, Column3=Data3}]
```

This is of type `List<Map<String, Object>>`. How to convert this to a Map of type `<String, String>`, with values split with '='for a key value pair

Comment: Hi Arvind! The problem is now resolved. Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(Map<String, Object> element: list) {
        for(Entry<String, Object> entry : element.entrySet()) {
            newMap.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```